# Why does my principal component analysis output report the p-value as being "NA"?

Tags: r, probability, pca, p-value

I have a dataset with 89 observations from a survey. 3 of my questions load well into 1 factor and the output looks relatively sensible. However, when it says that the root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.21 with the empirical chi square  22.63  with prob <  NA. Why is it saying "with prob < NA" and what does that mean? I have no missing values.

````
> pc1
Principal Components Analysis
Call: principal(r = attitudes_q_part, nfactors = 1, rotate = "oblimin", 
    n.obs = 89, scores = TRUE)
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
     PC1   h2   u2 com
AQ1 0.68 0.46 0.54   1
AQ2 0.81 0.65 0.35   1
AQ3 0.81 0.65 0.35   1

                PC1
SS loadings    1.77
Proportion Var 0.59

Mean item complexity =  1
Test of the hypothesis that 1 component is sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.21 
 with the empirical chi square  22.63  with prob <  NA 

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.72```
````